# Why two definitions of 'reverse' in Haskell's Data.List

Tags: haskell

Looking at the [source of Data.List](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.0/docs/src/GHC-List.html#reverse) shows `reverse` defined as

```
#ifdef USE_REPORT_PRELUDE
reverse                 =  foldl (flip (:)) []
#else
reverse l =  rev l []
  where
    rev []     a = a
    rev (x:xs) a = rev xs (x:a)
#endif
```

I would like to know why the second definition is provided? Is it superior in some sense?

**EDIT:**

As @n.m. comments below, the second version is "like a straightforward rewrite of the first version, with `foldl` expanded and `flip (:)` inlined into it." Indeed, Data.List itself defines `foldl` as

```
foldl        :: (b -> a -> b) -> b -> [a] -> b
foldl f z0 xs0 = lgo z0 xs0
             where
                lgo z []     =  z
                lgo z (x:xs) = lgo (f z x) xs
```

It is impossible to know the motivation of the authors of Data.List (unless one of them happens to visit this page), but as a beginner is it OK if I write code like the first version of `reverse` and leave the compiler to do the inlining for me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can compile copies of these two versions and see what ghc outputs.

```
module Rev where

myReverse1                 =  foldl (flip (:)) []
myReverse2 l =  rev l []
  where
    rev []     a = a
    rev (x:xs) a = rev xs (x:a)
```

Building with `-ddump-simpl` to see the generated core, and `-dsuppress-all` to eliminate some irrelevant noise:

```
rwbarton@morphism:/tmp$ ghc -O -ddump-simpl -dsuppress-all -fforce-recomp Rev
[1 of 1] Compiling Rev              ( Rev.hs, Rev.o )

==================== Tidy Core ====================
Result size of Tidy Core = {terms: 40, types: 58, coercions: 0}

Rec {
myReverse3
myReverse3 =
  \ @ a_aNh z_aNB ds_aNC ->
    case ds_aNC of _ {
      [] -> z_aNB;
      : x_aNH xs_aNI -> myReverse3 (: x_aNH z_aNB) xs_aNI
    }
end Rec }

myReverse1
myReverse1 = \ @ a_aNh xs0_aNz -> myReverse3 ([]) xs0_aNz

Rec {
myReverse4
myReverse4 =
  \ @ a_aMV ds_dNu a1_auj ->
    case ds_dNu of _ {
      [] -> a1_auj;
      : x_auk xs_aul -> myReverse4 xs_aul (: x_auk a1_auj)
    }
end Rec }

myReverse2
myReverse2 = \ @ a_aMV l_auh -> myReverse4 l_auh ([])
```

Examination of `myReverse3` versus `myReverse4` shows that they are the same, except that they take their arguments in the opposite order. Indeed, you can see that `lgo` in `foldl` has its arguments reversed from `rev` in `myReverse2`. I'm pretty sure there is no noticeable performance difference as a result of this, and if there is it's unintentional.

So, yes, with optimizations GHC will compile the two definitions of `reverse` to essentially the same thing. My guesses for why the inlined definition exists are

- The implementation of most of the standard library dates from a very long time ago and used to be shared between GHC, Hugs, and a couple of other Haskell compilers. Maybe GHC or one of the other systems was not so good at optimization back then.
- It's still slightly useful today to have these manually optimized versions, when doing GHC development: <s>it's commonplace to build the compiler and its libraries with optimizations disabled (since it's significantly faster), and then manual optimizations like this one means the resulting compiler, and the programs it produces, are more efficient</s> actually, I checked and the common "quick" BuildFlavour still builds the libraries with `-O`, so there is not much truth to this after all.

Answer (score 14):

I believe that the first version,

```
reverse                 =  foldl (flip (:)) []
```

is the version of `reverse` defined in the *Haskell Report*, and the second version

```
reverse l =  rev l []
  where
    rev []     a = a
    rev (x:xs) a = rev xs (x:a)
```

is an equivalent function which is more efficient.  You can see that the second version uses an accumulation parameter so the whole thing is a tail call, which is very efficient on most Haskell implementations.

The second version is the one provided by default, perhaps the first one is provided so that the compiler writers can test how well programs perform with the more concise function definitions in the report.

**Note:** it appears others came to the same conclusion, in [a post to haskell-cafe](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lang.haskell.cafe/75673).

Comment: What's not clear is why exactly the second version is more efficient. It looks like a straightforward rewrite of the first version, with `foldl` expanded and `flip (:)` inlined into it.

Comment: @n.m. Perhaps there is no difference on higher optimization levels.

Comment: Maybe it's the opposite. `fold` if present is faster because it's the mother of all TCO functions and therefore might be super optimized

Comment: With the introduction of http://www.joachim-breitner.de/publications/CallArity-TFP.pdf it may actually be that we want to switch back.

That said, in general the transformation here is a win. 

It goes back to John Hughes work in the 80s: http://www.cs.tufts.edu/~nr/cs257/archive/john-hughes/lists.pdf

And became a poster-child for what is now called the worker-wrapper transform.

Comment: @EdwardKmett Could you please elaborate a bit, perhaps in an answer? As n.m. points out, the difference in the two versions of reverse is that of an inlined function. Hughes seems to be comparing the linear time reverse (which both versions here are) to the inefficient quadratic time reverse. The implication of Breitner's paper is also not clear to me since it seems to me that the whole list needs to be generated and allocated before it can be reversed. As a beginner I know I may be missing something very basic, so a little clarification would help.

Comment: @JyotirmoyBhattacharya, I don't know what Edward Kmett means about the worker-wrapper transformation here, but it turns out he's right about the effect of the call arity optimization (combined with the `foldl`-as-`foldr` definition it optimizes). In particular, it fuses with `map` on either side, to reverse and map in one pass. It also plays nicely with a fusion-friendly version of `unfoldr` I'm pushing to include in the next version of the libraries, so that `reverse (unfoldr f q)` builds a single list tail-recursively. `reverse` is always bad, but (cont)

Comment: (cont) thanks to Breitner's work it can now be less bad.

Comment: To clarify: in order to fuse on both sides, the Prelude definition needs to be wrapped in `build`, but this is trivial. To clarify something else, while most/all realistic uses of `reverse` will still build a whole list (or equivalent) in memory, the fusing version can probably do more work per byte of garbage produced. Reducing garbage production in this fashion tends to improve L1 cache utilization.

Comment: gmane.org looks to be no more. I *think* that this piece is the relevant haskell-cafe article: https://mail.haskell.org/pipermail/haskell-cafe/2008-April/042186.html