# Why are there two definitions of init function in Prelude?

Tags: haskell

I found in Prelude two definitions of the function init:

```
init [x] = []
init (x:xs) = x : init xs
init [] = errorEmptyList "init"

init [] = errorEmptyList "init"
init (x:xs) = init' x xs
  where init' _ [] = []
        init' y (z:zs) = y : init' z zs
```

What is the reason of the second definition?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why two definitions of 'reverse' in Haskell's Data.List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24391077/why-two-definitions-of-reverse-in-haskells-data-list)

Answer (score 12):

You haven't quoted it verbatim. It's actually:

```
-- | Return all the elements of a list except the last one.
-- The list must be non-empty.
init                    :: [a] -> [a]
#if defined(USE_REPORT_PRELUDE)
init [x]                =  []
init (x:xs)             =  x : init xs
init []                 =  errorEmptyList "init"
#else
-- eliminate repeated cases
init []                 =  errorEmptyList "init"
init (x:xs)             =  init' x xs
  where init' _ []     = []
        init' y (z:zs) = y : init' z zs
#endif
```

The `USE_REPORT_PRELUDE` means that this piece of code adheres to Haskell Report, while the other one is a potentially more efficient implementation. Check out [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24391077/why-two-definitions-of-reverse-in-haskells-data-list) for similar discussion about `reverse`.

Comment: I don't understand why the second definition is more efficient.

Comment: @allmass At each iteration, one definition branches over three possible cases (`[x],(x:xs),[]`), the other one only two (`[],(z:zs)`), so -other things being equal- it requires fewer checks/jumps. Further, `[x]` requires matching two constructors since it's the same thing as `x:[]`, which should cost twice, roughly, the cost of matching against `[]` or `z:zs`, which have a single constructor. (This is not a completely accurate description, but it's close enough to understand, I think)

Comment: But I have read that patterns are analysed from top to bottom until the first pattern fits and the rest of patterns are ignored. Why the third pattern in the first definition is checked at each iteration, or maybe I  don't  understand the rule "from top to bottom" properly?

Comment: That analysis holds for generating the code, but the actual code generated may be more efficient (and optimizable) if it only has 2 choices to consider rather than 3.

Comment: @allmass it isn't. checking for `[]` is part of the *first* clause's pattern match, not the third's: `[x]` is actually `(:) x []` (as chi notes), so not only we have to check that it is `:`, but also that it has `[]` in its right branch. that's two checks for one pattern to match.

Comment: @allmass, "top-to-bottom" is a good way to think about the *semantics* of the pattern match, but it's actually compiled into a tree of jumps.  It doesn't actually check the patterns one by one, it is just specified to give the same answer as if it did.

Comment: Why not more minimally?  `ini [x] = []; ini (x:xs) = x:ini xs`

Comment: @fp_mora That's the first version if you look closely.

Comment: @bartek-banachewicz That is why assumptions are so bad, assuming the 2nd only matters. ugh